# Beginner here... is the anode and cathode of the TLV431 mixed up in the linked circuit?

Tags: batteries, protection, undervoltage

From an earlier question, I know I need discharge protection on the NiMH batteries in another circuit I'm working on. Researching it led me to [this link](https://easyeda.com/iONic/low-voltage-cutoff-circuit-using-tl431-voltage-reference).

It looks to me like the anode and cathode are connected the wrong way round, with the cathode connected to ground. I thought it should be the other way round. Can someone please confirm this - or tell me where my understanding is flawed?

Thanks :)

Comment: Tip: wherever possible, add the relevant, cropped portion of the schematic into your question so that we can understand the question without following links. Remember that links may die, making your question useless to future readers. Credit the authors, of course, as per [site policy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schematic is wrong, but the pin numbers are correct.

[image]

[image]

Some versions of TL431 from some manufacturers have different pinouts. I guess whoever made this schematic used such a symbol from a different version and just wired it according to the pin numbers. It's quite misleading...

[image]

Comment: Thank you, bobflux. That's cleared up my confusion. Maybe I'm not as green as I'm cabbage-looking :D